# How can I set the "default" worksheet with xlwt?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I'm using Python and **xlwt** to create Excel files:

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
# ... fill Sheet1 with some data ...
ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet2')
# ... fill Sheet2 with some data ...
wb.save('test.xls')
```

When I open the created file I see **Sheet1**. Would it be possible to set the "default" worksheet to something else with xlwt? For example, I would like to see **Sheet2** when I open the file. I don't want to re-order the sheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`workbook.active_sheet` is a sheet index and defaults to 0. In your specific case above, you would do `wb.active_sheet = 1`.

Note: Currently, this forces the index of the first visible tab in the worksheet tab bar to be the same number. If you really don't like that idea, join the python-excel google-group and make a case for it being settable independently.

Comment: Thank you! In my case the mentioned side effect is acceptable